# .NET SSH port forwarding

Tags: c#, .net, networking, ssh, portforwarding

I am trying to build in SSH port forwarding into a .NET application that I am writing.

I have tried using [sharpSSH](http://www.tamirgal.com/blog/page/SharpSSH.aspx), but it requires the user to input their password every time, and I don't want that. I am going to handle storing the password.

I have downloaded [Granados](http://granados.sourceforge.net/), but there is basically zero documentation for it. How do I accomplish port forwarding with Granados or any other **free** SSH library for .NET?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you set up an DSA key on the SSH server remotely, you could save a key for the user (do this as a one-time thing) and then save the key on the server as an authorized user.

Comment: using keys is a lot dangerous for reverse connecxions and Fingerprint

Answer (score 20):

The [SSH.NET library](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET) is a simple way to achieve this:

```
using (var client = new SshClient("client.net", "user", "password"))
{
    client.Connect();

    var port = new ForwardedPortLocal("localhost", 10000, "remote.net", 80);
    client.AddForwardedPort(port);

    port.Exception += delegate(object sender, ExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Exception.ToString());
    };
    port.Start();

    // ... hold the port open ... //

    port.Stop();
    client.Disconnect();
}
```

Comment: This is old and i might not get an answer but, is client.net the server running the SSH server? What would remote.net be?
Any request to localhost:1000 will be sent to client.net which will then forward the request to remote.net:80? Is that right? Or will it go directly to remote.net from my localhost?

Comment: Yes, client.net is the SSH server.  remote.net:80 is the computer that you want to connect to via the SSH tunnel.  As you state, any request to localhost:10000 will be sent to client.net via SSH which will then forward the request to remote.net:80.  Therefore there is no direct connection between localhost and remote.net.

Comment: actually, that code does not work, for some reason SSH.NET doesn't resolve localhost correctly, 127.0.0.1 seems to work fine though; thought this had to do with my network configuration, anyway using localhost is not robust here

Comment: is there any tutorial on how to configure the .net ssh server?

Comment: I've been trying to get this working, and it looks like you can leave the `localhost` off the port `ForwardedPortLocal` call - the disadvantage is that then any IP can connect to the SSH server on port 10000 and it will be forwarded to `remote.net:80`.  If that's not a security problem in your case you're fine - otherwise you'll need to figure out your local hostname or IP and put that instead of localhost.

Comment: Figured out why "localhost" doesn't work, but "127.0.0.1" does. Here is where it's going wrong. In ForwardedLocalPort's private `InternalStart` method, it calls  `IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(DnsAbstraction.GetHostAddresses(this.BoundHost)[0]`. So it's performing its own DNS resolution on BoundHost (via Dns.GetHostAddresses) and then arbitrarily choosing the one at [0]. The two entries actually returned are ["::1","127.0.0.1"]. So it's binding to an IPv6 loopback address by default. This isn't compatible with, for example, my IPv4 drivers/etc/hosts entries or IPv4 port proxies.

Answer (score 4):

These C# alternatives are all derived from JCraft's Java [Jsch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/):

1. [sharpSSH](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sharpssh) (inactive since Jan 2010) / [author's page](http://www.tamirgal.com/blog/page/SharpSSH.aspx) / [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/sharpssh.aspx)
2. [DotNetSSH](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dotnetssh/) (inactive since Jun 2010)
3. [SSH.NET Library](http://sshnet.codeplex.com/) (active as of Jan 2012)
4. [Nsch](https://github.com/mono/ngit/tree/master/NSch) (generated/updated from Jsch Feb 2012)

The Granados [product page](http://www.routrek.co.jp/en/product/varaterm/granados.html) links to the [Poderosa](http://poderosa.sourceforge.net/) project which includes a [PortForwarding plugin](http://poderosa.sourceforge.net/). The [source code](http://poderosa.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/poderosa/src/PortForwarding/) for the [channel.cs](http://poderosa.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/poderosa/src/PortForwarding/channel.cs?content-type=text/plain) and [connectionmanager.cs](http://poderosa.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/poderosa/src/PortForwarding/connectionmanager.cs?content-type=text/plain) files there appear to implement port forwarding. See this answer for [a recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4881941/423430).

[Nsch](https://github.com/mono/ngit/tree/master/NSch) appears to be a hidden gem within MonoDevelop's [NGit](http://monodevelop.com/Download/What%27s_new_in_MonoDevelop_2.6#GIT.c2.a0Support); it is [mostly-automatically converted](https://github.com/mono/ngit/tree/master/gen) ([background info](http://foodformonkeys.blogspot.com/2010/10/ngit.html)) from Jsch.

[Further research](https://web.archive.org/web/20110228073025/http://blog.kowalczyk.info/article/8twh/bterm-research-notes.html) in Feb 2011 by [Krzysztof Kowalczyk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2898/krzysztof-kowalczyk) of Sumatra PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method without promoting any of these `parameters:` **(Fully-automated port forwarding)** using [SharpSSH](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sharpssh/)

**(user,host,Lport,Rhost,Rport,DSA-key-confirmation,Password)**

```
    Dim JJ As Tamir.SharpSsh.jsch.JSch = New Tamir.SharpSsh.jsch.JSch()
    Dim sess As Tamir.SharpSsh.jsch.Session = JJ.getSession("user", "remoteadd.dydns.com")
    Dim conf As Hashtable = New Hashtable()
    conf.Add("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no")
    sess.setConfig(conf)
    sess.setPassword("password")
    sess.connect()
    sess.setPortForwardingR(45, "127.0.0.1", 256)
```

Answer (score 0):

Although poorly documented - or at least the documentation eludes me - this seems to be able to handle SSH connections including file transfers and port forwarding: https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET