# how to retrieve iphone contacts to my windows form application c#?

Tags: c#, iphone, windows, contacts

i want to be a program for receive iphone contacts (for windows application not ios) 
and add new contact and delete contact like as iTools for windows.
backup and restore, delete all etc.
which reference can i use for this?

can anyone help me?

Comment: Unfortunately, because of how this site works, you must do some research on your own and start something. Once you run into trouble, come and ask for help. Alternatively, if you can rephrase your question to be more generic, and not so open-ended; you may get some answers.

Answer (score 0):

1. This will likely only work on a phone that is [jailbroken](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_jailbreaking) and gives you some mechanism to transfer files to/from the device, like [ssh/sftp/scp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell#File_transfer_protocols_using_SSH). See [C# Library for SSH and Telnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881587/c-sharp-library-for-ssh-and-telnet) for a discussion on using SSH from C#.
2. The contacts are stored in a SQLite database at this location: `/private/var/mobile/Library/AddressBook/AddressBook.sqlitedb`
3. That file is a [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/) database. See [Is there a .NET/C# wrapper for SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93654/is-there-a-net-c-wrapper-for-sqlite) for more information on accessign SQLite from C#.

Comment: thanks for your answer but if you know itools, it is not need to jailbreak, read contacts and more on not jailbroken device? but how to?